# whoami doesn't work after exporting dynamic library

Tags: linux, rhel8

I am working on a RHEL8 machine and trying to get the username using the **whoami** linux command line,  however once I export the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable I'm getting this error:

whoami: cannot find name for ID ...

Have anyone already run through this issue ?

***NOTE:***

1- This behavior only happens on RHEL8, the command works just well on RHEL7.

2- $USER is an alternative that works fine but I would like to keep my code consistente across different platforms.

Comment: try to preserve the ols library path `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/new/path/.../`

Comment: Yeah I already tried that but it didn't help !